# Mssql/Perl DBI performance woes

Tags: sql-server, perl, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, dbi

Im writing an application that does a lot of large inserts to a remote mssql server with Perl DBI.  Not sure if it will be 05 or 08 sql server yet, but I've timed it in both so far and performance is similar.  Basically, there are a large number of rows that need to be inserted are turning out to be the bottleneck by far.  I have tried multi-row inserts in 08 ( and the sub-select UNION ALL trick in 05), changing whether the inserts are fired off during a previous fetch or after, using execut_array() on single-row inserts, all these with/without binding params.

```
Psuedocode:

select data query
while fetchrow {
  do lots of calculations
  construct insert
  1) do inserts here
}
2) or do inserts here
```

The activity monitor on the sql server averages the multi-row inserts at 70ms a piece.  The queries themselves have been limited to 58ish rows a piece because there are 36 fields on the insert, and it easily hits the 2100 parameter limit.

Is there anything obvious I am overlooking?  Any other method I could try to improve the times?  Ignoring issues like latency or hardware, I feel like there has to be another improvement to my Perl workflow or the queries themselves.  (I was looking into sql server bcp, bulk inserts, etc).

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

execute_array will not make much difference because it is not implemented in DBD::ODBC (because I've never got around to it). As such it is really DBI just calling execute repeatedly for you.

I don't understand the 58ish rows, 36 parameters and hitting 2100 parameter limit although I can see 58 * 36 is pretty much 2100. If your insert needs 36 parameters just prepare it before the select and execute it in the while loop - that should be faster since the SQL does not need to be passed/parsed each insert.

Apart from that, it you can disable AutoCommit and commit at the end or regularly but less than once per insert it should be a lot faster. You may also have indexes/triggers etc on the table which can slow inserts down so you could look at disabling them until afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the response; its cool to see the active maintainers dishing out advice.

Yeah 2100/36 columns = 58 max rows per insert (i hate this, cant believe this is really a hard limitation).  I do prepare such queries once and execute with the an array of bind params each time.

I hadnt considered the AutoCommit - I will try that as well.  These tables have minimal (max is 2 i think) indexes for this very reason!   So if I disable AutoCommit, do I have to start each batch of queries with a BEGIN TRANSACTION? Or is everything in a transaction until you ->commit() ?

Comment: Disable AutoCommit in the DBI->connect call by setting it to 0. To start a txn use DBI's begin_work, then do some inserts and then a commit call (or in theory a rollback if you want to roll them back and finish the txn). So basically, read about commit, rollback and begin_work in the DBI pod.

Comment: By the way, I still don't get how a 2100 limitation affects you when you are only inserting 36 parameters per execute.

Comment: Im using multi-row insert queries eg "INSERT INTO x (a,b,c,...) VALUES (? x 36),(? x 36), ..."

Answer (score 1):

I guess Perl/DBI is a requirement (because this isn't running on Windows perhaps)?

Any possibility of using BCP (you would write an intermediate text file) or SSIS (you might be able to do everything in SSIS) or even ADO.NET SqlBulkCopy (in some kind of .NET environment)?  All these are specifically designed for large loads.

Comment: Yeah The application itself runs on an ubuntu server. I have considered BCP, havent tried it out yet.  That would pretty much work like 1) construct my queries 2) save to file (unsure of the difference between the formats) 3) push file to sql server 4) execute BULK INSERT query specifying datafile path; right?

Comment: @Andrew Parker Yes, that's basically it.